# Including copyrighted images

Tags: discussion, editing

In [my answer to the question *Comment traduire « To be on fire » ?*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2432), I noticed Gilles added an image reference to the cartoon Asterix.

Which is totally appropriate, and as a matter of fact I wanted to add the exact same image myself, but I felt that adding a copyrighted image would not be allowed by the license used for the SE sites.

Was I wrong, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, fair use (the US legal doctrine for uses that are permitted of a work covered by copyright) does allow such an illustration, which does not detract the audience of the cited work.

Evpok is right, I should have added the attribution — especially as the intent is to entice readers into reading *Astérix*, which is an icon of French culture and an interesting and funny source of insights into the French language.

Answer (score 5):

According to the US legislation, I think it could be considered as fair use. According to the French [*Code de la propriété intellectuelle*](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006278917)

> Lorsque l'oeuvre a été divulguée, l'auteur ne peut interdire :
>   […]
>   3° Sous réserve que soient indiqués clairement le nom de l'auteur et la source :
>
> a) Les analyses et courtes citations justifiées par le caractère critique, polémique, pédagogique, scientifique ou d'information de l'oeuvre à laquelle elles sont incorporées

So as long as the author's name and the source are mentionned (<s>wich is not the case as I write</s>) I don't think it infringes copyright. But I am not a legist.